# Update user properties in Active Directory using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, active-directory, crud

I am tring to make CRUD operations on Active Directory via nodejs.
The only package that handle CRUD operation in node that i have found is ad- 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ad.
Are you familiar with other packages? 
Is this the only one for update operations?
It seems that integration with Active Directory in nodejs is not popular and mature. Am I wrong? should I implement such integration in Java or .Net core?
Thanks!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way is the way that works :) If you are already using NodeJS, then do it in NodeJS if at all possible.

Communication with AD would happen through LDAP, so you can look for NodeJS packages for LDAP. Here are a couple I found:

- [ldapjs](http://ldapjs.org/)
- [ldap-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ldap-client)

But that [one you linked to](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ad) is more specific to AD (and AD does have its own flavor of LDAP) so I would choose that as long as it works for you.

If it doesn't work for whatever reason, either ask a new question here to get specific help, or you can start looking into making a separate Java or .NET app to do it. But I wouldn't consider a separate app just for AD queries unless you absolutely couldn't do it in NodeJS.